# How can I prevent PHP to HTML encode tags in saveHTMLFile?

Tags: php, dom, character-encoding

I have a small problem: the tags, e.g. `<br>` tags, are not parsed when submitting a PHP DomDocument. Here is my PHP code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("Test.html");
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$node = new DOMElement('p', 'This is a test<br>This should be a new line in the same paragraph');
$doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->appendChild($node);
$doc->saveHTMLFile("Test.html");
echo 'Editing successful.';
```

Here is the HTML code (before editing):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hey</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test</p>   
    </body>
</html>
```

(after editing)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hey</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>   
<p>This is a test&lt;br&gt;This should be a new line in the same paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Is that HTML sample the before or after condition?

Comment: So what is the after condition?

Comment: I ran it locally and the after is the before, with this appended to the end `<p>This is a test&lt;br&gt;This should be a new line in the same paragraph</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to append a [fragment](http://www.php.net/DOMDocumentFragment), which does not work as 'normal' string (how ever would it know what you want it to encode and what not?).

You *can* use the`DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML()` function, but as the name states, it wants `XML`, not `HTML`, so for this the `<br>` *needs* to be self-closing (because we are working in XML mode):

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("Test.html");
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$node = new DOMElement('p');
$p =  $doc->lastChild->lastChild->appendChild($node);
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('This is a test<br/>This should be a new line in the same paragraph');
$p->appendChild($fragment);
$doc->saveHTMLFile("Test.html");
```

Another solution not involving altering your string is to load a seperate document as HTML (so, `$otherdoc->loadHTML('<html><body>'.$yourstring.'</body></html>')`, and then loop through it importing in the main doc:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("Test.html");
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$node = new DOMElement('p');
$p =  $doc->lastChild->lastChild->appendChild($node);
$otherdoc = new DOMDocument();
$yourstring = 'This is a test<br>This should be a new line in the same paragraph';
$otherdoc->loadHTML('<html><body>'.$yourstring.'</body></html>');
foreach($otherdoc->lastChild->lastChild->childNodes as $node){
    $importednode = $doc->importNode($node);
    $p->appendChild($importednode);
}
$doc->saveHTMLFile("Test.html");
```

Comment: Nice, but I need this to work not only to append something, but also to use it for `insertBefore()`, later...

Comment: Using `insertBefore` for this isn't significantly different, you only need a reference to the node your want to be before, the rest remains equal.

Comment: Yeah, I added it in later, thinking you probably need a solution which involved not tampering with the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<br/>` rather than `<br>`? It could have to do with validity of the markup. `<br>` is invalid.

Comment: `<br>` is HTML, `<br/>` or `<br />` is XHTML. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)